# Rails dynamic redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need to create a dynamic redirection model for a rails app. Its sort of similar to wordpress redirection plugin, if you have used it anytime. http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

What the model will store is a `redirect_this_path` string, and the `final_path` it should be redirected to. So if a user comes to my app requesting for `redirect_this_path`, he would be redirected to `final_path`.

If however, there is no matching entry found in the database, the request should be forwarded to the other routes defined in `routes.rb` file. So, basically the redirection model will filter all requests and redirect the requests for which it has the data and relay the other requests to routes already defined in the `routes.rb` file.

Is there any way it can be achieved, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this: (for example in application controller)

```
def path_check
  if request.path == path_that_needs_redirecting
    redirect_to final_path
  end
end
```

Then simply use: (in application or every controller you need it in)

```
before_filter :path_check
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

If you have many paths that need redirecting just do

```
if paths_that_need_redirecting.include? request.path
```

Comment: Ah – this actually makes it much clearer what he was asking! :)

Comment: before_filter is deprecated from Rails 5. before_action can be used instead

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood right, but maybe this works for you?

On routes.rb:

`get 'redirect/path', to: redirect('final/path')`

Comment: Hi, this route needs to be hardcoded in your routes files. What if you  have 100+ paths that needs to be redirected? You need to hardcode that many lines in your `routes.rb` file. Each time you update your code, you will have to deploy it again. I want the `redirect_this_path` and the `final path` defined in a rails model and checked dynamically for a matching request.

Comment: match 'games/:permalink/:id/(:page)' => redirect {|params,request| "/gierki/#{params[:permalink]}" + params[:page].nil? ? "" : "/#{params[:page]}" }

Answer (score 0):

@Piotr Kruczek is close, but it sounds like you want to redirect each path to it's own unique `final_path` you will actually need to do something like this:

appliction_controller.rb

```
before_filter :path_check

def path_check
  if ModelName.find_by_column_name(request.path)
    redirect_to ModelName.find_by_column_name(request.path).final_path
  else
    redirect_to deafult_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way - define custom url helper and put all the magic in there. But more interesting way... is to hack inside of the Rails and beat the sh*t out of it. For example: [ActionDispatch and url_for](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ce06d57e390c03cf5438410efc8345c60d961e05/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb). I'm not sure, but maybe that's the point where you could implement custom routing mechanism:

```
  def url_for(options = nil)
    case options
    when nil
      _routes.url_for(url_options.symbolize_keys)
    when Hash
      _routes.url_for(options.symbolize_keys.reverse_merge!(url_options))
    when String
      options
    when Array
      polymorphic_url(options, options.extract_options!)
    else
      polymorphic_url(options)
    end
  end
```

I believe that using parameters supplied to this method, you will be able to instantiate model and request a custom url from it (or proceed with basic processing if something went wrong).

However, monkey patching Rails... it smells. Cleaner way is to extract it to the separate gem and cover it by your own test suite.